# Can't disable password complexity windows 8.1 home

Tags: windows-8.1, passwords, security-policy

I have a simple Windows 8.1 Home Edition PC, with a local account (no email associated with user). When I try to change password it MUST meet complexity requirements (upper, lower, special, character) to include length and history. Now, I am at my wits end because I am a certified pro who has been doing this for a long time.

I have tried `secpol.msc` (which doesn't exist) so I used `gpedit.msc`. ALL the settings are correct, they are all disabled or set to zero. I have scoured the registry looking for something that may help. I have even tried "Password Policy Enforcer" which usually works, and it says the policy is changed to allow a simple six character password like "helpme". Unfortunately I can't get that to work either. I can't find anything online either.

Please, I need fresh eyes on this issue, what am I missing?

Comment: There is no such thing as 'Windows 8.1 Home Edition' it's more commonly simply called 'Windows 8.1 Core'

Comment: If you're frustrated about this only when signing in (at the lock screen), you can set it to a 4 digit PIN.

Comment: obligatory xkcd => http://xkcd.com/936/

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the password policy settings.
Open Local Security Policy (a simple search should find this "panel")
- Click on the arrow next to Account Policies (left side)
- Click on Password Policy (left side)
- Make your changes (right side)

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to reset password? If you can't set in Windows, I think you can get help from **Windows password recovery tool**, you may search them on Google, these tools can help you reset password to blank, you can try.

Comment: I do not want to simply reset the password. Read the post. I want to make it a simple password, but my computer is forcing a complex password, despite the changes I have made to policy.